# Файлы из локального хранилища android

Tags: java, android

Как в приложение реализовать загрузку файлов (фото, документов) из локального хранилища пользователя android?

Comment: конкретизируйте проблему, с чем именно у вас возникли сложности?

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко то выглядит это примерно так:

```
String fileName = "myFile.txt";
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+fileName;
File file = new File(path);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```